# Solrcache and requesthandler

Tags: solr, query-cache, requesthandler

Due to my proj security requirements, i have created a custom requesthandler(for eg:"/new") to serve requests coming from a particular set of users & i have the default "/select" requesthandler to serve the requests from another set of users.This distinction is made to make them search over different set of fields (qf). My querystring (say, q="car") sent to /new handler , fetches 100 results & the same (q="car") sent to /select , gives 50 results. Will these query results for
each requesthandler be handled separately or be taken from the same cache.

In short, is the Solr requesthandlers tied to its own querycache?

Answer (score 0):

From all caches in Solr the most important regarding queries is the filterCache. If properly setup, and if the queries make use of fq, it will have a great impact usually.

It is my understanding filterCache is shared among all request handlers.

The other caches, documentCache, queryResultCache etc, have much less importance.